# interceptor: timeout modal with retry

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to write an angular interceptor (I am on ionic).
The goal is to intercept timeout out requests (let's assume that those have status -1), show a modal, and retry until the connection goes through.
The interceptor seems behaving as expected but when the connection is restored, nothing happens. I am afraid it is not correct to have the `return $http(rejection.config);` inside the `$timeout`.

```
services.config(['$httpProvider', function($httpProvider) {
  $httpProvider.interceptors.push(function($injector, $q, $timeout) {
    return {
      // we use the incerceptor to assign a timeout property to every http request
      request: function (config) {
          config.timeout = 5000;
          return config;
      },
      responseError: function(rejection) {
        // We assume timeouts have status=-1
        var $http = $injector.get("$http");
        var $rootScope = $injector.get("$rootScope");
        // duration defines how long the modal screen will be open (in seconds)
        var duration = 5;
        var showModalAndRetry = function(rejection) {
          $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then( function() {
            $rootScope.$broadcast("app.somethingWentWrong");
            $timeout(angular.noop, duration * 1000).then( function () {
              $rootScope.$broadcast("app.closeSomethingWentWrong");
              console.log("resending");
              console.log(rejection);
              return $http(rejection.config);
            });
          });
         };
        switch(rejection.status) {
          case -1:
            return showModalAndRetry(rejection);
        }
        return $q.reject(rejection);
      }
    }
  });
}]);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I am afraid it is not correct to have the return `$http(rejection.config);` inside the $timeout*

> ```
>   //ERRONEOUS
>   var showModalAndRetry = function(rejection) {
>       $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then( function() {
>         $rootScope.$broadcast("app.somethingWentWrong");
>         $timeout(angular.noop, duration * 1000).then( function () {
>           $rootScope.$broadcast("app.closeSomethingWentWrong");
>           console.log("resending");
>           console.log(rejection);
>           return $http(rejection.config);
>         });
>       });
>      };
> ```

The `.then` method of a promise returns a new promise that resolves to what is returned to the function given to the `.then` method. It is important to return that new promise to the parent function. Otherwise the parent function returns a value of `undefined`.

```
//INSTEAD
function showModalAndRetry (rejection) {
  //vvvv RETURN timeout promise
  return $timeout(angular.noop, 1000).then( function() {
    $rootScope.$broadcast("app.somethingWentWrong");
    //vvvv RETURN timeout promise
    return $timeout(angular.noop, duration * 1000).then( function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("app.closeSomethingWentWrong");
      console.log(rejection);
      return $http(rejection.config);
    });
  });
};
```

In this case there is a `$timeout` promise nested inside another `$timeout` promise. There needs to be a `return` statement for each level of nesting.

The [DEMO on PLNKR.](https://plnkr.co/edit/6Ep50cfXhpz2pR5I9Aim?p=preview)

---

To avoid "pyramid of doom" nesting, the promises can be chained:

```
function showModalAndRetry (rejection) {
  //vvvv RETURN timeout promise
  return $timeout(null, 1000)
    .then( function() {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("app.somethingWentWrong");
      //vvvv RETURN timeout promise
      return $timeout(null, duration * 1000);
  }).then( function () {
      $rootScope.$broadcast("app.closeSomethingWentWrong");
      console.log(rejection);
      //vvvv RETURN httpPromise
      return $http(rejection.config);
  });
};
```

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Got it.